# Create customer with default addresses via API

Tags: magento2, customer, api, magento2.3, rest-api

Is it possible to create customer via API and set default billing and shipping address at once ?

I know that in customerCustomerRepositoryV1 and 
customerAccountManagementV1  are fields like `default_billing` and `default_shipping` but there is required to set addressId.
In case when we are creating customer there is no id for sending addresses.

I am using Magento 2.3.1